# Proof Verification: Surjectivity and injectivity of a piecewise function.

Tags: functions, proof-verification

The following is a function such that $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$
In this case, $f(x)$ = {$x$ when $x$ is rational, $2x$ when $x$ is irrational}

Determine whether $f$ is injective, surjective, or neither. Prove your answer.

To prove whether $f$ is injective:
If $x$ is rational, then $f(x)$ is rational. If $x$ is irrational, then $f(x)$ is irrational.  Therefore, two elements $x$ and $y$ in which $f(x) = f(y)$ must either be both rational or both irrational.
Case 1: Both Rational
Suppose $f(a) = f(b)$. Therefore, $a = b$.
Case 2: Both Irrational
Suppose $f(a) = f(b)$. Therefore, $2a = 2b$, and $a = b$.
The function is injective.

To prove whether $f$ is surjective:
Case 1: Rational
Take any element $y \in {R}$. Then $y = f(y)$.
Thus, every $y \in {R}$ is equal to $f(x)$ for every $x = y$.
Case 2: Irrational
Take any element $y \in {R}$. Then $y = 2(y/2) = f(y/2)$.
Thus, every $y \in {R}$ is equal to f(x) for every $x = y/2$.
The function is surjective.

Therefore, the function is bijective.
Thanks for any help, just want to make sure I'm on the right track.

Comment: Everything looks fine except you say "subjective" when it should be "surjective."

Comment: Thank you. That was what I meant. Fixed.